# Anchor a <div> to top of the browser window

Tags: javascript, css

I need to anchor a div to the top of the browser

No matter where the user is when the div is shown, i need to make sure it is on the top, until the user closes it

This is different from stackoverflow, where the notifications sticks to the top of the body, rather than the window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you can simply use:

```
#elementSelector {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zuppf/)

Comment: The only reason I tend to use `left` and `right` is to force the width to be `100%` of the browser-window, without worrying about `margin` and/or `padding`. Feel free to adjust to taste, of course :)

Comment: makes total sense. thanks! do you know if this works on mobile browsers?

Comment: Only by testing it, or posting a demo that's likely to get high traffic (and, obviously, providing a feedback/bug-report option)...I suspect that it won't work on iPhone, given the issues it has with `position: absolute;`, but I've not tested, or researched, to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

try using:

```
<div id='stickyTop'></div> << or any other div/id u want to stick at the top
```

css:

```
#stickyTop: { /* or any other div/id u want to stick at the top*/
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```